# MVC 5 - RedirectToAction Not Redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I have a problem with my RedirectToAction not redirecting. My code successfully hits a breakpoint placed on the Redirect so I can confirm it is being called. Nothing seems to happen however.

I have tried looking at the network traffic in Chrome and there doesn't seem to be anything obvious. I must be missing something simple!

```
    //
    // POST: /Blog/CreateBlog
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateBlog(BlogViewModel model)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        model.UserId = userId;

        if (ModelState.IsValid && model.UserId != null)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<BlogViewModel, Blog>();
            if (_blogProcess.CreateBlog(Mapper.Map<BlogViewModel, Blog>(model)))
            {
                RedirectToAction("Index", "Blog");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

try

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Blog");
```

Comment: Jeebus... overlooking that little keyword is a serious slap to the face.  Thank you for checking our sanity!

Comment: This was very helpful. Can't believe or understand why I left out the return keyword.

Answer (score 3):

In addtion to Nalaka526's answer: if we look into the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470594%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for `RedirectToAction` we can see that it's an instance method of the `Controller` class which has [`RedirectToRouteResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirecttorouteresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) as return type, which derives from [`ActionResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which indicates that we have to `return` it, just like we return `View` and `PartialView` for example.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using @using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Blog"..) on the view page then

   ```
   public ActionResult CreateBlog(BlogViewModel model)
   {
       ....
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Blog") 
   }
   ```

   should work.
2. If you are using `Ajax.BeginForm`, then you need to redirect to a new action/url from javascript `OnSuccess` event.
   sample code for your view

   ```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Blog", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post" , OnSuccess="RedirectFunction"}

   function RedirectFunction(data)
   {
       window.location.href = “Index”;
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes.. I have used Ajax. I am still having the issue. Can you please link the docs where we can learn about ajax in MVC. if possible can u elaborate the answer?