# RedirectToAction immediately

Tags: c#, .net

## Problem

---

Hi, I'm trying to redirect to a different action in my controller when a `Department` can't be found. My problem is that it does not redirect immediately after I hit the code block. I'm not sure if it is the correct method to use for this, but to me it seemed like it should work. I would also prefer not using `Response.Redirect(url);` because that just seems a bit messy to me.

## Code

---

```
if(errors.Count > 0)
{
    RedirectToAction("Index", "Department"); //Redirect to the index page, because the department could not be found
}
```

## Additionally

---

Is there also a nice way to send an error to the `Index()` action? Would/Could/Should I do that with a viewbag for instance, or is that really only for the views?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW there's a duplicate of the first half of this question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491271/mvc-5-redirecttoaction-not-redirecting?rq=1

Comment: @lc. Cheers, couldn't find anything. Guess I was searching for the wrong criteria (namely "immediately").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`RedirectToAction(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470594%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) returns a `RedirectToActionResult` which you in turn need to `return` from the controller method:

```
if(errors.Count > 0)
{
    //Redirect to the index page, because the department could not be found
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Department"); 
}
```

---

As far as saving an error state, you can use the `TempData` container, which will survive the redirect but not persist longer. (See also [Proper use of TempData in ASP.NET MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737022/proper-use-of-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc3)). For example:

```
TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "The department was not found";
```

You can then check for data in your `Index()` method and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Nice, concise and answers both my questions!

Answer (score 3):

You need to *return* the redirect result:

```
if(errors.Count > 0)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Department"); //Redirect to the index page, because the department could not be found
}
```

That way the execution of the method ends and the `ActionResult` is returned to the client, which in this case is a `RedirectToAction` result.

Essentially, in MVC one of the goals is to de-couple the code from the HTTP context.  So instead of operating on the `Response` object directly (as with a `Response.Redirect()`), you simply return different response types form the action methods.

Comment: Thanks that does the trick! Wasn't aware of that part :) Also cheers for the explanation about `Redirect`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you return the result

`return RedirectToAction("Index", "Department"); //Redirect to the index page, because the department could not be found`

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this 
`return RedirectToAction("Action","Controller");`

take a look here.

[Reference](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/4XDc110313-return-View()-vs-return-RedirectToAction()-vs-return-Redirect()-vs-return-RedirectToRoute().html)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**send an error to the Index()**

I assume you want to show error in Index(), Use TempData and render it on Index().

You can check null and show it in Index();